# TI Digital Mirror Devices: Raspberry Pi access to the DLPDLCR2000EVM

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I am having a hard time getting a response when accessing the DLP2000 evm from my Rpi3, "Raspberry Pi". I have used *I2cset* and *I2cget* to interact with the EVM.

*I2cdetect* identifies the `0x1b` for the 2607 and `0x57` for the EEprom. Reading from any of the preset registers returns `00` in all cases.

Have tried to activate any of the test images, using reg `0x11` for test pattern generation, with no result, my commands were:

```
i2cset -y 1 0x1b 0x11 0x3 i   # This should show a green screen 

No change!!1
```

Has anybody been successful with using an Rpi3 with the eval module?

Comment: Hi @Samir -- Welcome to StackOverflow!  Did you know that there is StackExchange site dedicated to Raspberry Pi questions and answers?  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/  I think you are more likely to get a answer if you also post your question there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, David, I will  repost at the rpi exchange.